# What happens with IF command when I pipe to it?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd, pipe, io-redirection

Here is my script:

```
   @echo off
    echo.|if defined 1 geq 1 echo 1 is geq than 1
    echo.|if defined 2 gtr 100 echo 2 is gtr than 100

    echo.|if 1 gtr gtr 100 echo 1 is gteater than 100
    echo.|if 100 lss gtr 100 echo 100 is gteater and the same time less than 100
```

the output is :

```
1 is geq than 1
2 is gtr than 100
1 is gteater than 100
100 is gteater and the same time less than 100
```

What is going with `IF` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch parser concatenates the first tokens after the `IF`.

To gain an insight you can use the `cmdcmdline` variable.

From a batch file

```
@echo off
echo pipe | if defined 1 geq 1 echo %%cmdcmdline%%
```

In the output you can see that `defined` and `1` are concatenated, so this is the cause for the strange results

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" if defined1 geq 1 echo
>   %cmdcmdline%"

When you test this from the command line you need to modify the `%%cmdcmdline%%` to `%^cmdcmdline%` as the cmd-parser works a bit different with percent expansions.

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
if defined 1 geq 1 echo 1 is geq than 1
```

to this:

```
if defined 1 if 1 geq 1 echo 1 is geq than 1
```

Comment: In most of the cases I know how to deal with if command :-) . The question is a little bit misleading and I've asked it more for the fun than  anything else.The main point is why here `IF` is behaving like that .I think it's a bug in `IF` - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5539&p=33837#p33837    - But will be good if can confirm this.

Comment: I know you are keen on experimenting with syntax, to figure out how it works and new ways to do things.  I think it's a little off topic for SO though.  Dostips is a better place, but could use some more eyes and testers.