# Using IF inside FOR loop with piped content inside CMD

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, cmd

I am writing one batch setup program, and I have to check version of java during the setup.
In order to do that I use the following code in my batch:

```
JAVA -version 2>&1 | FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "VERSION" /I`) DO (IF 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
```

But for some reason this does not work, there appears the following error message:

> ```
> 2 was unexpected at this time.
> ```

If I do not pipe command to `FOR` loop then `IF` command gets executed.
If I put `ECHO` outside `IF` while piping, and do not use `IF`, `ECHO` gets executed.

So for some reason combination of piping and `IF` command does not work.
What should I do?

Comment: even stranger: `if 2 equ 2` does not work (also `if "2" equ "2"` doesn't) , but `if 2 == 2` works...

Comment: i contacted microsoft, and told them about those strange things which are happening to me, and guess what they told me? they told me that i should reinstall windows. omg, they are so stupid, hahahaha. they do not have a clue what they are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot explain why it does not work (I receive `2 was unexpected at this time.`); but guess it has something to do with the fact that `IF` is one of the commands (`FOR`, `IF`, `REM`) that are recognised earlier than all the others by the command interpreter `CMD`, together with the fact that a pipe (`|`) initialises new `CMD` instances for either side.

There are some options however:

1. Place the `JAVA` command also into the `FOR /F` loop:

   ```cmd
   FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`JAVA -version 2^>^&1 ^| FIND "version" /I`) DO (IF 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
   ```
2. Use a temporary file:

   1. Read the temporary file within the `FOR /F` loop:

      ```cmd
      JAVA -version > "%TEMP%\file.tmp" 2>&1
      FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`^< "%TEMP%\file.tmp" FIND "version" /I`) DO (IF 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
      DEL "%TEMP%\file.tmp"
      ```
   2. Read the temporary file outside of `FOR /F` loop:

      ```cmd
      JAVA -version > "%TEMP%\file.tmp" 2>&1
      < "%TEMP%\file.tmp" (FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "version" /I`) DO (IF 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.))
      DEL "%TEMP%\file.tmp"
      ```
3. Wrap around another `CMD` instance explicitly to hide the pipe from the `IF` command:

   ```cmd
   JAVA -version 2>&1 | CMD /C FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "VERSION" /I`) DO (IF 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
   ```

---

Strange findings:

- [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082) found out another work-around: using comparison operator `==` instead of `EQU` -- see [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269263/using-if-inside-for-loop-with-piped-content-inside-cmd/42270116#comment71696340_42269263); but this does no longer allow true numeric integer comparisons anymore:

  ```cmd
  JAVA -version 2>&1 | FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "VERSION" /I`) DO (IF 2 == 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
  ```
- When you escape (at least) the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> immediately behind `IF` by `^`, the command line works unexpectedly:

  ```cmd
  JAVA -version 2>&1 | FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "VERSION" /I`) DO (IF^ 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
  ```
- Insert `REM/ ^&` immediately in front of `IF`:

  ```cmd
  JAVA -version 2>&1 | FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "VERSION" /I`) DO (REM/ ^& IF 2 EQU 2 ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
  ```

---

Take also a look into this very interesting related thread: [What happens with IF command when I pipe to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23185370)

Comment: i guess this strange behavior is actually a bug in the cmd. i think microsoft should fix it.

Comment: yes, i get the same error. i think it is cmd bug. anyway, this what you have posted works great. thank you!

Comment: @SYOBSYOT - This behavior is not a bug, but rather an unfortunate consequence of how cmd.exe is designed. The IF statement gets parsed twice due to the pipe, which is a complication because the IF parser changes the line a bit. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194279/1012053 for an explanation of how pipes work and indirectly explains this behavior. Also see the answers by [enjoying](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42270214/1012053) and [MC ND](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42271095/1012053) that directly solve the parsing problem in other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763782/why-does-the-error-message-appear-when-if-comparison-is-in-the-piped-block-com/36787263#36787263)

So the code can be

```
JAVA -version 2>&1 | FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN (`FIND "VERSION" /I`) DO @(IF 2^  EQU %A ECHO INSIDE IF STATEMENT.)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is easier when you explicitly define the executables that conform the pipe

```dos
JAVA -version 2>&1 | CMD /C"FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=." %A IN ('FIND "VERSION" /I') DO IF %A EQU 8 ( ECHO Java 8 ) ELSE ( ECHO NO Java 8 )"
```