# How to pipe the final result of a windows batch for loop into another command

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

have my script splitted into two batch files as i dont know how to combine it:

short so you get an idea:

**1.bat** : calls 2.bat with args, sorts its output and makes lines unique

```
FOR /F ... (2.bat %1 ^| sort) DO (...)
```

the do part compares lines to each other and excludes identical lines using a linebuffer

**2.bat** : prints strings as a result of an FOR loop

```
FOR ... DO ECHO
```

in bash this might look like this: (piping is easy)

```
(command) | while read line ; do echo $line ; done | sort | uniq
```

i really dont know how to process the final output of a FOR loop in windows batch to use its result with another loop (without using temp files for result buffering)

This is the whole code with jeb's solution applied:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM *** This "goto" to a label, if there is one embedded in %~0 -
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=3" %%L in ("%~0") do goto :%%L

REM *** The second part calls this batch file, but embedd a label to be called
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN (`echo dummy ^| call %~d0\:main:\..\%~pnx0 %1 ^| SORT`) DO (
    IF NOT "%%A"=="!buff!" SET str=!str!%%A
    SET buff=%%A
)
ECHO %str:.dll=;%
endlocal
GOTO :eof

REM *** This function will be called in the pipe, but runs in batch context
:main
CD %1
:sub
FOR %%A IN (*.dll *.exe) DO dumpbin /DEPENDENTS %%A | FINDSTR /I "DLL" | FINDSTR /V "Dump :"
FOR /D %%B IN (*) DO (
    CD %%B
    CALL :sub
    CD..
)
GOTO :eof
```

it returns a single line with runtime dependencies of all files inside a ***folder*** [arg1] and all its subfolders : the .dll part of the output string is stripped to suit my needs

ADVAPI32;COMCTL32;COMDLG32;GDI32;KERNEL32;ole32;SHELL32;USER32;WININET;

here is the counterpart on osx using pev tools:

```
#!/bin/sh
find "${1}" -type f \( -iname "*.dll" -o -iname "*.exe" \) | while read pe ; do
    readpe -i "${pe}" | grep -i '.dll' | awk '{print $2}'
done | sort | uniq | sed 's/.[dD][lL][lL]//g;' | tr '\n' ';' ## have the BSD sed release and can't use I with sed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is simple

```
command | (
    for /f "delims=" %%L in ('more') DO @(
       echo # %%L
    )
) | sort
```

But it's get nasty when you really want to make more than a simple echo.
The next code will fail at the `IF 1 NEQ 2`

```
echo dummy | (
    for /f "delims=" %%L in ('more') DO @(
        echo # %%L
        if 1 NEQ 2 echo Not Equal
    ) 
)
```

This has different (complex) reasons, you can read at [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/463115) and  [What happens with IF command when I pipe to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23185370/463115)

To be able to use the loop without problems you can use a call-function-wrapper.

```
@echo off
REM *** This "goto" to a label, if there is one embedded in %~0 -
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=3" %%L in ("%~0") do goto :%%L

REM *** The second part calls this batch file, but embedd a label to be called
echo dummy | call %~d0\:myFunc:\..\%~pnx0 | sort
exit /b 

REM *** This function will be called in the pipe, but runs in batch context
:myFunc
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('more') DO @(
    echo # %%L
    if 1 NEQ 2 echo Not Equal
) 
exit /b
```

**How the self-calling works:**

```
call %~d0\:myFunc:\..\%~pnx0
```

This expands to the full path of the batch, assuming the batch is `C:\temp\myFile.bat` then the result will be:
`call C:\:myFunc:\..\temp\myFile.bat`
This is strange but still a valid path, because `:myFunc:` will not be evaluated as the `\..\` part will remove the previous part.
So the batch file calls itself.

The trick is, that `:myFunc:` is still part of the %0 variable.

`FOR /F "delims=: tokens=3" %%L in ("%~0") do goto :%%L`
This part splits the `%0` by `:` into
`"C", "\", "myFunc" and "\..\temp\myFile.bat"`
And the use the third token (`myFunc`) for the `goto %%L`.

The advantage of this technic is, it doesn't break existing batch files and their parameter handling.
You could put the function also into `%1` but then it's hard to guess if the batch shall use `%1` as a goto destination or use it as a normal parameter.

Comment: I tried echoing the `%~d0\:myFunc:\..\%~pnx0` portion of your example code and couldn't make sense of it.  I've looked everywhere and the only info I can find shows how to call a second batch file or how to call a function in the current one.  If I understand your code comments correctly, it appears that you're both calling a file (new instance of the current one) and one of it's functions in the same line of code.  Would you please tell me how that works in more detail?

Comment: @ChrisD I added `How the self-calling works:`, I hope it answers your question