# Batch - Run functions in the same file async from each other function

Tags: multithreading, function, batch-file, asynchronous

I have **one single** Batch file with 2 functions in it:
1.) `MAIN`
2.) `ASYNC`

Now i try to call the `ASYNC` function out of the `MAIN` function without waiting for the completion of the `ASYNC`function. Is that possible?
*Here is my Batch file:*

```
@echo off
:MAIN
setlocal
echo Here i am in the Main Thread
start /b :ASYNC
echo Here i am in the Main Thread again
endlocal
exit /b 0

:ASYNC
setlocal
echo I am in the ASYNC Thread
timeout /T 100
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

Is there any possibility to run a function in a single batchfile asynchron from another function in the same batchfile without separating the functions to multiple files?

Greets & Thank you :D

Comment: Yes, change `start /b :ASYNC` to `start "" /B cmd /D /C call "%~f0" :ASYNC`, then insert before `:MAIN` the line `if not "%~1"=="" goto %~1`, but note, that `:ASYNC` becomes executed in a new `cmd.exe` instance then…

Comment: Or as a better but more complex method: replace `start /b :ASYNC` by `start "" /B cmd /D /C "%~d0\:ASYNC:\..%~dpn0" %*` and insert before `:MAIN` the line `for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%Z in ("%~0") do goto :%%Z`…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possibility: use [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to let the script restart itself, provide the label of the sub-routine as an [argument](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and use [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) rather than [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to continue execution at that point:

```cmd
@echo off
if not "%~1"=="" goto %~1
:MAIN
setlocal
echo Here I am in the MAIN thread
start "" /B cmd /D /C "%~f0" :ASYNC
echo Here I am in the MAIN thread again
endlocal
exit /b 0

:ASYNC
setlocal
echo Now I am in the ASYNC thread
timeout /T 10
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

When you run the script and want to first execute the main section, you must not provide an argument. If you do, it will be interpreted as a jump label. To avoid that, you could check whether the (first) argument begins with a `:` and skip the `goto` if not. Replace the line `if not "%~1"=="" goto %~1` by the following to achieve that:

```cmd
set "ARG1=%~1" & if not defined ARG1 shift /1 & goto :MAIN
if "%ARG1:~,1%"==":" goto %ARG1%
```

This is not absolutely safe against any odd arguments (like `"&"&`), but it will serve well in most situations. However, regard that the argument positions may not be as expected, because of the additional label argument (check out the argument string `%*`, which is even not going to be affected by [`shift`](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)).

Note, that the sub-routine then becomes executed in a new `cmd.exe` instance, so any environment changes will not reach the main instance.

---

There is even a better way to accomplish what you want, without affecting any potential arguments, namely to embed the label of the sub-routine in the script path itself when restarting the script (technique courtesy of user [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/user/463115), see his answer to [How to pipe the final result of a windows batch for loop into another command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49250904)):

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%Z in ("%~0") do goto :%%Z
:MAIN
setlocal
echo Here I am in the MAIN thread
start "" /B cmd /D /C "%~d0\:ASYNC:\..%~pnx0" %*
echo Here I am in the MAIN thread again
endlocal
exit /b 0

:ASYNC
setlocal
echo Now I am in the ASYNC thread
timeout /T 10
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

The key portion is the augmented path string `%~d0\:ASYNC:\..%~pnx0`, which is going to be resolved to `%~d0%~pnx0` (that is the full script path `%~0`).

The sub-routine becomes again executed in a new `cmd.exe` instance.